# s3 method definition messing up with another package's s4 method

Tags: r, oop, methods, r-s4, r-s3

this question is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065696/error-in-getmethodsummary-signature-fitdiff).

I figured out that question has something with S3 summary methods I am programming to a class I am defining. I understand summary is already a S3 method. And I was able to specify it without setting:

```
summary<-function(data,...){
   UseMethod("summary",data)
}
```

And for what I know, it is working, for my summary methods.

But, when I try to use `semTools::compareFit` command, I realized that possibly I messed up something.

```
library(lavaan)
library(semTools)
data("HolzingerSwineford1939",package="lavaan")
HS.modelA <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9'

HS.modelB<- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9'

fit.A<- cfa(HS.modelA, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)           
fit.B<- cfa(HS.modelB, data = HolzingerSwineford1939)
a<-semTools::compareFit(fit.A,fit.B)
show(a)
```

returns:

```
Error in getMethod("summary", signature = "FitDiff") : 
  no method found for function 'summary' and signature FitDiff
```

That's weird. And I am unable to understand it clearly, as I am new in S3 S4 stuffs... But, taking a look on the `semTools::CompareFit` function definition ([here](https://rdrr.io/cran/semTools/src/R/compareFit.R)), I see it has something to some summary method (if I understood correctly, a S4 method)

and I believe that's also why

```
 result<-semTools::compareFit(fit.A,fit.B)
semTools::saveFile(result, file="",what="summary", tableFormat=FALSE)
```

returns

> Length   Class    Mode

> ```
>   1 FitDiff      S4
> ```

from which I suppose the issue has something with the S3method messing up the S4 method dispatch...

The problem appears just when I load the package in which I am joining the functions (which includes the `summary` method mentioned above).

I am aware of the way to set the default methods like...

```
summary.default<-function(data, ...){
   base::summary(data)
}
```

Which I understood is not required as the `summary` function is already a generic function. And in fact, is not the solution as the problem is with `CompareFit`, not a summary method...

I am aware of the following related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100856/combining-s4-and-s3-methods-in-a-single-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709933/adding-s4-dispatch-to-base-r-s3-generic?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Also, we do not see any `summary` function when we try `?semTools::summary`...
From the `semTools::CompareFit` documentation, the `summary` method is internal (or whatever... not sure)... or an alias for something else (I am very confused about..)

How can we make such arrangement for an internal method of an already available package?...
Or how to avoid this kind of problem? or how to specify S3 method adequately to avoid or circumvent this kind of problem?

I appreciate any help. I am really very confused with this S3 and S4 method stuffs...

---

### **Update**

This is really an issue with S3 methods messing up the S4 method dispatch.

If I load `showMethods(summary)` before loading the semTools package, I get:

```
Function "summary":
 <not an S4 generic function>)
```

But if I load `showMethods(summary)` after loading it, I get:

```
Function: summary (package base)
object="ANY"
object="FitDiff"
    (inherited from: object="ANY")
object="lavaan"
object="lavaanList"
object="mle"
```

---

I am circumventing the problem for now assessing the output object structure and formalizing a specific `summary.FitDiff` object to extract the informations... [which solves in my current problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63600180/8939181), but not for the potential of messing up any other s4 method...

The ideal solution should involve something with how to specify s3 methods without messing up all possible s4method.

Comment: First, this must be the summary called by semTools: `semTools:::summary.lavaan.mi`. You need to use `:::` instead of `::` to see it because it's not an exported function

Comment: Second, can you create a reproducible example where I can get your same error? Because your code works fine to me.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your effort here... Unfortunately I am not able to know what exactly is causing that to make it reproducible...

Comment: Let's dig into it.. clean your environment and restart R with Ctrl+Shift+F10. Then run your code till that error and launch `sessionInfo()`. Add the result to your question, please

Comment: I just imagine it's something with the s3 method... Now as you taught me about detaching the libraries in the other question, I will try to see how to reproduce it... thank you very much.

Comment: I was aware of semTools::summary.lavaan.mi, but I thought it was not related, as the object class appears to be FitDiff, not lavaan.mi... but I really do not understand nothing about S4 methods... So, can it be solved specifying a summary.FitDiff method directing to summary.lavaan.mi?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218555/discussion-between-edo-and-hamagust).